# wordpress blog page adding year/month folder to other page url's

Tags: wordpress

I seem to be getting the year/month folder adding to all my WordPress blog pages url's.

So on this page: www.mydomain.co.uk/2013/03/handleless-kitchens/

I will get: www.mydomain.co.uk/2013/03/talk-to-us/

instead of just: www.mydomain.co.uk/talk-to-us/

any ideas? this is only happening in the actual blog itself and not on the blog/news summary page etc.

TIA

using WordPress 3.5.1

Comment: There's a menu for that, I think it's named "Permalinks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the admin menu

```
Settings->Permalinks
```

Select Custom Structure and write

```
/%postname&
```

to  editbox

Comment: yes but wont that remove the folder to the blog itself which I don't want.
Its just adding the extra to that particular page other urls/link from that page

Comment: There is no real directories present at the blog. Those are address structures that created by Wordpress engine.

Comment: as the site is established I don't want to suddenly change the blog structure... if you look at http://www.liebekuchen.co.uk/2013/03/handleless-kitchens/
and hover over say the top "find a showroom" link, look at the link url... it's added the folders into it.

Comment: @richsb it's not going to remove the folder of the blog itself. But it's of course going to change the folder structure (by adding the sub-folders `2013` and `03`), that's what you are telling it to do

Comment: If you mean "Links added to posts written before changing permalink structure stays same" you should change those by hand.

Comment: ok.. by changing from month & name in permalinks to /%postname& the blog now at http://www.liebekuchen.co.uk/2013/03/handleless-kitchens/ becomes a 404, what I thought would happen and want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

from admin panel goto settings->permalink  and select the type of structure you want to show ..